# .bash_history vs history command

Tags: bash, command-history

When I open my `.bash_history` file and view my previous commands via the `history` command, I see that they are not the same exact commands ?

I feel like the `.bash_history` commands contains less commands, is it because the `.bash_history` is updated every 24 hours or so ?

Also I wonder is there a limit for the number of commands to appear in my `history` or `.bash_history` file ?

Answer (score 4):

What a particular process keeps in memory for the history will vary with what is in a history file depending on a variety of settings and commands, notably the `HISTCONTROL`, `HISTFILE`, `HISTFILESIZE`, `HISTIGNORE`, and `HISTSIZE` environment variables, and the `fc` and `history` commands, though [the history section of the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Using-History-Interactively) will doubtless make for better reading than this.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the `history` command as the temporary storage for the commands you are currently entering into your console/terminal window. You can think of it as a working list of your current commands.

Conversely, the history of all the commands you have ever recorded in your consoles/terminals, in your current and previous sessions, which are then conveniently appended as a file in your file system profile, i.e. `.bash_history`.

Further useful information can be found in [Why is history and .bash_history different and how to delete an entry in history?](//askubuntu.com/q/1029850) on Ask Ubuntu.